# redirect after click button delete

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have problem when I click button edit, I hope I can redirect to

```
http://localhost/activity/edit_activity/172
```

where 172 is `activity_id` but actually i redirect `activity_detail` so here my code

**My HTML**

```
<a href='<?php echo site_url();?>activity/delete_activity_edit/<?php echo $row->activity_detail_id;?>' onclick='return confirm()' class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>Delete</a>
```

**My Controller**

```
public function delete_activity_edit()
    {

        $id=$this->uri->segment(3);
        $this->activity->remove($id);
        redirect('activity/edit_activity/'.$id);
    }
```

**My Model**

```
public function remove($id)
    {
        $where_array = array(
        'activity_detail_id'=>$id);
        $this->db->where($where_array);
        $this->db->delete('t_trx_activity_detail');

    }
```

Where is my wrong code. And how to resolve it?

Comment: What you get when you click that link?

Comment: In your question you said you are click on edit link and in your code snippet you show delete button. Please be clear with your question. As your code shows you are deleting your records.

Comment: By the way, don't implement delete action with `GET` verb. `GET` verb is to retreive data from the server and not allowed to change data on server because it can be cached and served from cache without hitting the server. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-4.3.1

Comment: Just want to know did you got any exception in your code, if not then try with core PHP header location function if that works or not, so that we can figure out the exact issue.

Comment: I didn't get you what is your issue

Comment: after i click button delete,this page reloaded.so i want reloaded in same page,but actually after delete redirect the other page

Comment: Put an `$id` parameter to `delete_activity_edit($id)` method. And use $id from there, not from `uri->segment`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code format:

```
<a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='confirm_delete(<?php echo $row->activity_detail_id;?>)' class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>Delete</a>
```

Add this javascript function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var url="<?php echo base_url();?>";
    function confirm_delete(id){
       var r=confirm("Do you want to delete this?")
        if (r==true)
          window.location = url+"activity/delete_activity_edit/"+id;
        else
          return false;
        } 
</script>
```

Now your controller redirection works.

Comment: in controller like what

Comment: No changes in controller and model.

Comment: still problem,i hope i can redirect activity_id not activity_detail_id.i remove data sort by activity_detail_id and redirect sort by activity_id

Comment: Do you use javascript confirm_delete function as i suggest for redirection to controller. Because with this it is redirect successfully.

Comment: Can you send me your code change because if you use code format as suggest in answer then it works.

Comment: In your code you send this id "<?php echo $row->activity_detail_id;?>" thats why it is redirecting to function. You need to change it to <?php echo $row->activity_id;?> if you want to redirect this id.

Comment: default page is http://localhost/activity/edit_activity/172 //activity_id and in default pege there data with activity_detail_id

Comment: i want redirect activity_id

Comment: Your link must be consists of both details [ACTIVITY_ID] AND ALSO [ACTIVITY_DETAIL_ID] also then you can get this by segments and pass in to javascript function.

Comment: Or you can find by select query your [ACTIVITY ID] from [ACTIVITY_DETAIL_ID] in to your controller and then redirect by that [ACTIVITY_ID].

Comment: can you give me example

Comment: As you create url like this : http://localhost/activity/edit_activity/172. Example 6 is your ACTIVITY_ID then create your link like this :

Comment: http://localhost/activity/edit_activity/6/172 and call by segment method.